# Sorting HTML list by child attribute with Tinysort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, tinysort

I would like to sort this list with [Tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) by using the 1st `TIME` element of the `LI` element.

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">John</a>
            <div class="bubble">
                <p><strong>John</strong></p>
                <p>
                    <time datetime="01/01/1950">01/01/1950</time> -
                    <time datetime="10/02/2005">10/02/2005</time>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Alice</a>
            <div class="bubble">
                <p>Alice</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mary</a>
            <div class="bubble">
                <p>Mary</p>
                <p>
                    <time datetime="01/02/1920">01/02/1920</time> -
                    <time datetime="01/02/2015">01/02/2015</time>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So in my case it should say: Mary - John - Alice (or less correct, but acceptable, could be: Alice - Mary - John).

I have tried

```
tinysort('.box ul>li', {selector:'time',attr:'datetime'});
```

But it is messing my list and only sorting the `bubble` `div`, not the `li`. Also, any element without `time` is simply ignored, because it is not pointing to the `li`.

Alternatively I could add a time attribute inside the `li` element, but the less I get the HTML dirty, the better, since such attribute does not really add any semantics. Any suggestions to sort the list with as few HTML modifications as possible? Potentially what I want is to make *tinysort* aware that I want to sort the `li`s and not the `bubble`s.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the attribute you are trying to sort on is not a number so it is handled like a string. Add a Unix timestamp the time element or the list-element and sort on that. You can do this server-side or client-side.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sjeiti/o9kv8be2/
And here's the code (I was lazy and added the timestamp to the list-element, but you probably should add it to the time element):

```
var listElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0, l = listElements.length; i < l; i++) {
  var li = listElements[i],
    time = li.querySelector('time'),
    date = time && new Date(time.getAttribute('datetime'));
  date && li.setAttribute('data-timestamp', date.getTime());
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  tinysort(listElements, {
    data: 'timestamp'
  });
});
```

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to work (?) - I added the data-timestamp. In any case, a similar solution was clear to me which requires to modify the HTML... There is no other way?

Comment: Fiddles external resource had disappeared, fixed now. There are always other ways, but from the top of my head this is the easiest/cleanest solution I can think of.

Comment: This is working quite good, except that in my example, it sorts the elements with null timestamp first. The console prints null on var date (obviously) and those LI are not modified. Also, for the records I had a mistake and my dates were actually European style (dd/mm/yyyy) so I just changed them to yyyy-mm-dd in the HTML.